# Exclude records

Tags: sql

I need to exclude data based on two columns present on another table.

Table1 has 2 columns a and b.
Table2 has 3 columns a,b,c. column B and C represents range.for some records we do not have range. example given below.

Table 2 data,

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
1           1         10
2           5         NULL
2           8         NULL
2          25         50
3          10         100
4           7         10
4           2         NULL
```

We need to exclude records from table 1 based on table 2 data. table1.column A = table2.column A and table 1.column b between tabl2.column b and table2.column c.

Table 1 has hundreds of records, but we need to exclude table2 data from table1 data. in table1 sample data given below.

```
ColumnA Column B
1        4
1       14
1       15
2        1
2        5
```

we need to exclude 1st record and 5th record from table 2.

Please help me in resolving this issue asap?

Comment: Asking for help "ASAP" generally has the opposite effect on SO.

Comment: What does a `NULL` represent in `Table2.ColumnC`? No upper bound? Does the same apply to `ColumnB` (ie, no lower bound)?

Comment: @Tony: time to think up "ALAP" ;-)

Comment: users with 1 pt do not get special treatment, especially help ASAP

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that a `NULL` in either `Column B` or `Column C` in `Table2` represents no lower or upper bound to the range, respectively.

Try this

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2
    WHERE Table1.ColumnA = Table2.ColumnA
    AND ((
        Table2.ColumnC IS NULL
        AND Table1.ColumnB >= Table2.ColumnB
    ) OR (
        Table2.ColumnB IS NULL
        AND Table1.ColumnB <= Table2.ColumnC
    ) OR (
        Table1.ColumnB BETWEEN Table2.ColumnB AND Table2.ColumnC
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of needed information missing from this question in order to competently answer it so I'll list my assumptions up front. In the future, adding the SQL vendor you're using, and the meaning of your data will assist people is helping you.

I'm assuming that you're using MSSQL 2008 R2, that the data in Table 2 represents a series of exclusionary ranges for which a value from Table 1 should not be allowed to fall into, and that a NULL value in column C means that the range is open-ended.

With all of that being said the answer to your question can be most easily answered through the use of joins. If this is a new concept for you, you may want to review this post on joins in relational DBs http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html as well as the JOIN documentation for your specific RDBMS.

In MSSQL you would accomplish this by doing something like the following:

```
With ValuesInRange
AS
(
   Select distinct ColumnA, ColumnB from Table1 
   Join Table2 on Table1.A = Table2.A
   AND Table1.ColumnB >= Table2.ColumnA 
   AND Table1.ColumnB <= isnull(Table2.ColumnC, Table1.ColumnB)
)
Select * from Table1 a
OUTER Join ValuesInRange b 
ON a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA AND a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB
Where b.ColumnA IS NULL
```

By using a CTE you avoid needing to reissue the query for every row and should get marginally better performance. If you only have several hundred rows though this shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: thanks for this.  I need to exclude records for a different reason (No Nulls) and I think your answer just might work for me.  I was trying to avoid the old SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD NOT IN (SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE)